# How to name and cite different versions of Microsoft Kinect?

Tags: citations, computer-science, writing

There are at least two types of Kinect cameras, one is called Kinect for Xbox 360 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#/media/File:Xbox-360-Kinect-Standalone.png)
and another one is called Kinect for Xbox One (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#/media/File:Xbox-One-Kinect.jpg).

First, do they have shorter names (eg. Kinect v1 and Kinect v2) widely accepted in the research community? Moreover, how would you cite them in a scientific paper?

I'm now sure if this question is more appropriate for *UX* stackexchange or for the *academica* stackexchange. Kindly let me know in the comments. Thank!

Comment: yeah, it is called Kinect V1 and V2. In the research community, it is widely accepted, just because it is their name, [example](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0139913) here.

Comment: @GautierC. Thanks. As far as I can tell though, Kinect V1 and V2 are not official names. Even though Microsoft sometimes refer to the now discontinued Kinect for Windows V2 as Kinect V2, Kinect for Xbox One seems to be the official name for the current sensor. But if they are recognized as Kinect v1 and v2 in the research community, guess I will be using them as well.

Comment: For what I know, I always saw Kinect v1 (or Kinect V1) etc... No it is not the official name, but the common one. Maybe highlight it somewhere at the beginning of your article, then spoke about it with V1 and V2.

Comment: @GautierC Thanks. Please write your comments as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I checked a bit more, and as I though, it is commonly accepted :)

Comment: If you really want to get into the nitty-gritty, you could always try to find the hardware revision numbers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is commonly called Kinect V1 and V2. In the research community, it is widely accepted, just because it is their name, [example](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0139913) here.

Note that it is not the true name, as you stated. The best thing I could think of, is to highlight at the beginning of your article (or in the part you spoke about Kinect) that Kinect V1 refers to Kinect for XBox 360 and Kinect V2 refers to Kinect for XBox One (note there is a standalone version for Windows).